# How to configure Hikari Connection pool to recreate a connection after it is returned to the pool?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, hikaricp

Is there a way to configure Hikari to re-create a JDBC connection when it is returned to the pool. Here is the behaviour I am looking for.

1. App asks for connection it gets quickly because the pool has unused connections
2. App uses the connection
3. App calls .close() and Hikari returns the connection to the pool. Asynchronously Hikari should close the connection and re-open it.

I know the above behaviour is strange. There are "reasons" why I need to do this but not worth sharing in the question. Folks have asked for an elaboration on the reasons, here it is.

There are temporary database tables being created within a stored procedure. Those temp tables are tied to the lifetime of a connection. I need all these tables dropped before the connection is reused so that the next user of the connection does not inherit any state from these temporary tables. I don't know why the devs who wrote the code used temporary tables they way they are using it.

If there is a way to drop all temp tables just before the connection is returned to the connection pool then that is fine too.

In a Spring Boot app is there a Hikari settings to force re-creation of the connection every time it is returned to the pool?

Comment: This is a rather curious requirement. I don't think HikariCP can fulfill it for you. The only available knobs would be `maxLifetime` (which has a minimum of 30 seconds) and `idleTimeout` (minimum of 10 seconds, and not applied when there are only `minimumIdle` connections in the pool).

Comment: Considering the idea of pooling is to *avoid* really closing the connection when you "close" it, I doubt hikari has a regular setting for it (and if it did, you'd have found it already). HikariCP also has a very [low extensibility](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/141) (in order to achieve its high speed), so you're not given too many options to adjust the behaviour (at least in any "clean" way). But while you consider your next move, you could share a bit of the situation that requires you to cycle a connection when you return it to the pool. It sounds at least interesting.

Comment: ok I have elaborated the "reasons" in the question.

Comment: Which database system are you using? Maybe there is a statement that allows to connection state to be reset.

Comment: The database is MySQL

Comment: Probably the best solution is to add `DROP TEMPORARY  TABLE  IF EXISTS` before each `CREATE TEMPORARY  TABLE`. The second best is not to use a connection pool...